# How to clear only "Column A" with Google Apps Script before updating with latest content in the same column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to clear the contents of "column A" before "Update" function fills the latest data in the same column. The idea is remove any redundant data that is not required.

Usecase: Update all the tabs in one Index sheet, if people delete a sheet - that should not reflect in this Index sheet. Here is the code I have used after some research. I am new to this so need some help.

EDIT: Also how to exclude certain "Sheets" from the "Update" function so it doesn't show up in the Index column?

````
function onOpen() {
 
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 ui.createMenu('Index Menu')
     .addItem('Create Index', 'createIndex')
     .addItem('Update Index', 'updateIndex')
     .addToUi();
}


// function to create the index
function createIndex() {
 
 // Get all the different sheet IDs
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 
 var namesArray = sheetNamesIds(sheets);
 
 var indexSheetNames = namesArray[0];
 var indexSheetIds = namesArray[1];
 
 // check if sheet called sheet called already exists
 // if no index sheet exists, create one
 if (ss.getSheetByName('index') == null) {
   
   var indexSheet = ss.insertSheet('Index',0);
   
 }
 // if sheet called index does exist, prompt user for a different name or option to cancel
 else {
   
   var indexNewName = Browser.inputBox('The name Index is already being used, please choose a different name:', 'Please choose another name', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
   
   if (indexNewName != 'cancel') {
     var indexSheet = ss.insertSheet(indexNewName,0);
   }
   else {
     Browser.msgBox('No index sheet created');
   }
   
 }
 
 // add sheet title, sheet names and hyperlink formulas
 if (indexSheet) {
   
   printIndex(indexSheet,indexSheetNames,indexSheetIds);

 }
   
}



// function to update the index, assumes index is the first sheet in the workbook
 
function updateIndex() {
 
 // Get all the different sheet IDs
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 var indexSheet = sheets[0];
 
 var namesArray = sheetNamesIds(sheets);
 
 var indexSheetNames = namesArray[0];
 var indexSheetIds = namesArray[1];
 
 printIndex(indexSheet,indexSheetNames,indexSheetIds);
}

// function to clear index
function clearContentsOnly() {
var range = SpreadsheetApp
              .getActive()
              .getSheetByName("Index")
              .getRange(4,2,2,2);
range.clearContent();
}

// function to print out the index
function printIndex(sheet,names,formulas) {
 
 
 
 sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue('Task Index').setFontWeight('bold');
 sheet.getRange(7,1,formulas.length,1).setFormulas(formulas);
 
}


// function to create array of sheet names and sheet ids
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
 
 var indexSheetNames = [];
 var indexSheetIds = [];
 
 // create array of sheet names and sheet gids
 sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
   indexSheetNames.push([sheet.getSheetName()]);
   indexSheetIds.push(['=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXX/edit#gid=' 
                       + sheet.getSheetId() 
                       + '","' 
                       + sheet.getSheetName() 
                       + '")']);
 });
 
 return [indexSheetNames, indexSheetIds];
 
} ```
````

Comment: Better to share the link of copy of the sheet with public edit access

Answer (score 1):

clear contents of column A

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).clearContent();
```

if you have header rows and you specify the start row:

```
const sr = 2;
sheet.getRange( sr, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - sr + 1).clearContent();
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, where exactly should I add this link of code?

Comment: I added this under Print index function and it worked immediately. 

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateIndex() {
 
 // Get all the different sheet IDs
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 var indexSheet = sheets[0]; //better to use the name of the index sheet - as the sheet position may get changed easily by the user

 indexSheet.GetRange("A2:A").clearContent(); //add this line
 
 var namesArray = sheetNamesIds(sheets);
 
 var indexSheetNames = namesArray[0];
 var indexSheetIds = namesArray[1];
 
 printIndex(indexSheet,indexSheetNames,indexSheetIds);
}
```

Comment: Hi Arul, thank you so much for the code. I added the line as it is but yet I don't see any difference why I run the code. Am I missing anything here?

As I mentioned, I do not want to see deleted sheets in the index "column A" after every "update".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a Sheet with the name "Index" and then the following code will update column A with all Sheets and directly link to the respective sheet. It will add new sheets with the name and url below existing entries. And if a sheet has changed its name (but not its id), then it will update the sheet name.

```js
function updateIndex(){
    const ACTIVE = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    const spreadsheetURL = ACTIVE.getUrl()
    const currentIndexSheet = ACTIVE.getSheetByName("Index")
  
    // Empty the sheet
    currentIndexSheet.getRange("A1:A").clearContent()

    // We will populate this with all rows
    let outputRows = []

    // List Sheets which should not be listed
    let skipSheets = ["Index", "Another Sheet to Skip"]
    
    // Add Header Row
    outputRows.push(['="Linked Sheet"'])
    
    // Get all Sheet and add them to the outputRows using a Hyperlink
    ACTIVE.getSheets().forEach( sheet => {

      // Skip certain sheets which are defined above
      if( skipSheets.indexOf(sheet.getName()) != - 1) return  

      outputRows.push([`=HYPERLINK("${spreadsheetURL}#gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}", "${sheet.getName()}")`])  
    })

    // Write everything to Index
    currentIndexSheet.getRange(1,1, outputRows.length).setFormulas(outputRows)
}
```

Comment: Hello Neven, 

Thanks for the code, I added this code to the existing script and ran it yet I did not see any change. Do I have remove the previous code and replace it with this? Is there an additional single line code or command that I can add to my existing code just to clear only column A before the update function runs?

Comment: I've simplified it and made sure it clears the content, now it should be as you wish. When you run it, make sure you open your script file from the Sheet. Also make sure that one Sheet in your Spreadsheet exists titled `Index`. Then you can run the code.

Comment: I replaced the current "Update" function code with yours and I get this error "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 80 file: Code.gs" - so I am not able to save or run it. The current code that I have, I have enabled to to automatically trigger every 30 minutes so I need not be on the sheet or manual update the Index list but would this require to manually update?

Comment: sorry, I had fixed the code but made a mistake. Now it is fixed and can run automatically.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, I see this error now "TypeError: currentIndexSheet.clearContent is not a function". 

I only want to clear "column A" before it get's updated with latest list of sheets

Comment: No problem, I updated it so now that there is a formula in the field which directly links to the respective sheet.

Comment: Thanks Neven, the aspect where it directly links to the respective sheet makes it so easy. 

Is there a way I can exclude certain sheets so it does't show on the index link when we run update function? Thanks again

Comment: Sure, see now, you have `skipSheets` where you can add as many sheets as you like to the array and all of them will not be listed on the Index Sheet.

Comment: Wow, you are a saviour!

Thank you, trying it right away.